# how to use ftp by only one port?

Tags: port

```
listen=80
port_enable=yes
pasv_enable=no
```

I have set up a ftp server in my server. I want my classmates to use the ftp in the dormitory.
But the 80 port is the only one which can be used.The port 20,21 and other ports are all unable.I tried my best to make it worked.But I failed.Please tell me how to configure the ftp with the only 80 port.Thanks :) 
I disabled the pasv-mode.Is it right?
My server is based on the centos. I use the vsftpd. I have shut down the iptables and seLinux.  The firewall is in front of my server. Others ports are disabled by this firewall.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you will not be able to do that using real FTP - unfortunately, FTP protocol is not very firewall friendly, as it does require one command channel port (20 by default) and range of data ports (as many ports as many parallel connections supported), even in passive mode.

To solve your problem, you can setup WebDAV service, for example using [Apache mod_dav](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav.html).

Windows supports WebDAV out of the box. WebDAV allows clients to mount shares as if they were real file shares, and read/write content. Best news for you, it only needs one port (say, 80) to work.

Comment: Thank you very much!You gave a great choice to me.Thanks :)